# PLINK execution of: echo -e "%UNIXPW%\n" ^| sudo -S nginx -t -c, works OK on one, fails on another

Tags: command-line, 16.04, scripts

My batch file runs a PLINK script in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which works correctly on my own VM/Ubuntu.

The same command fails in when run on a different VM/ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
echo -e "%UNIXPW%\n" ^| sudo -S nginx -t -c /home/%UNIXUSR%/Documents/%FILENAME%%EXT% ^&^> /home/%UNIXUSR%/Documents/%FILENAME%Result%TXTEXT% > "%FILEPATH%%FILENAME%%SHEXT%"
```

Both Ubuntu's have only 1 user and the PLINK session is using that user.

What would cause this and how do I fix it to that it runs correctly on both?

Comment: YOu say "command fails".  What do you mean by "command fails"?

Comment: Failure means the result of the command is:

[sudo] password for userName: Sorry, try again.

Answer (score 0):

The password in %UNIXPW% had some special characters that caused this to fail.

Changing the password to alphanumeric made it work on all ubuntu machines!